# How to resolve lifetime issues implementing streaming iterators

Tags: iterator, rust

**Not clearly a duplicate of the linked question**

This question is about returning a reference to the member of an owned struct, not about storing a reference to an owned value on the same object.

I'm hoping for some explanation, or some hints towards what is happening in the very specific case.

---

I'm using the [streaming iterators library](https://github.com/sfackler/streaming-iterator) to build runtime pipelines where the exact types of iterators are not known at compile time. For example, I want to construct a pipeline like

```
read a file > gunzip it > parse the contents > extract fields
```

To do this efficiently, borrowing slices across the iterators seems important. My best attempt at creating an iterator that gzip decompresses `[u8]`s passed in by another iterator is [in a playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ea3ca0a6591eabb1b74ae75f1317085e&version=stable).

The error produced is:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:48:50
   |
48 |         self.reader = gzip::Decoder::new(self.it.next().unwrap()).ok();
   |                                                  ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 47:5...
  --> src/main.rs:47:5
   |
47 | /     fn advance(&mut self) { 
48 | |         self.reader = gzip::Decoder::new(self.it.next().unwrap()).ok();
49 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:48:42
   |
48 |         self.reader = gzip::Decoder::new(self.it.next().unwrap()).ok();
   |                                          ^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 44:1...
  --> src/main.rs:44:1
   |
44 | / impl<'a> StreamingIterator for GunzipIter<'a> {
45 | |     type Item = gzip::Decoder<&'a [u8]>;
46 | |     
47 | |     fn advance(&mut self) { 
...  |
50 | |     fn get(&self) -> Option<&gzip::Decoder<&'a [u8]>> { Some(&(self.reader.unwrap())) }
51 | | }
   | |_^
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected std::option::Option<gzip::Decoder<&'a [u8]>>, found std::option::Option<gzip::Decoder<&[u8]>>)
  --> src/main.rs:48:23
   |
48 |         self.reader = gzip::Decoder::new(self.it.next().unwrap()).ok();
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There's [an example](https://github.com/sfackler/streaming-iterator/issues/4) from the library:

```
use streaming_iterator::StreamingIterator;

pub struct FakeStreamingIterator<'a, I, T>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a &'a T>,
    T: 'a + ?Sized,
{
    inner: Box<I>,
    current: Option<&'a &'a T>,
}

impl<'a, I, T> FakeStreamingIterator<'a, I, T>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a &'a T>,
    T: ?Sized,
{
    fn new(inner: I) -> FakeStreamingIterator<'a, I, T> {
        FakeStreamingIterator {
            inner: Box::new(inner),
            current: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, I, T> StreamingIterator for FakeStreamingIterator<'a, I, T>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a &'a T>,
    T: ?Sized,
{
    type Item = T;

    fn advance(&mut self) {
        self.current = self.inner.next();
    }
    fn get(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        self.current.map(|x| *x)
    }
}
```

That compiles fine, but a similar example that more closely matches my use-case doesn't:

```
use streaming_iterator::StreamingIterator;

pub struct FakeStreamingIterator<'a> {
    inner: Box<StreamingIterator<Item = [u8]>>,
    current: Option<&'a [u8]>,
}

impl<'a> FakeStreamingIterator<'a> {
    fn new(inner: Box<StreamingIterator<Item = [u8]>>) -> FakeStreamingIterator<'a> {
        FakeStreamingIterator {
            inner: inner,
            current: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> StreamingIterator for FakeStreamingIterator<'a> {
    type Item = [u8];

    fn advance(&mut self) {
        self.current = self.inner.next();
    }
    fn get(&self) -> Option<&[u8]> {
        self.current.map(|x| x)
    }
}
```

The error always comes down to lifetime mismatches, but I don't understand how to resolve this.  The main differences, as I can see are:

- I'm holding a `Box` of a trait, rather than a `Box` of a type. This is needed because the parent iterator is not known at compile time.
- I'm using a slice rather than a reference to a reference. I don't understand why that would affect lifetimes.

In my mind, there are two logical lifetimes in play:

1. The lifetime of the iterator
2. The lifetime of the current slice.

The slice lifetime must be shorter than the iterator lifetime.  I'm assuming there's a situation where Rust can guarantee that `advance(&mut)` isn't called while there's an active borrow from the result of `get(&)` alive, but am not sure how this can be written.

I've read a lot about borrows and lifetimes, but don't understand the difference in this situation.

Comment: Not really an answer, but a possibility would be to use a memory pool with fixed size buffers and pass the buffer around. Pre-allocate X buffers, and never allocate again ever.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the issue without a more concrete and compilable example.

Comment: @NovaDenizen - Sorry, I had attempted to simplify the problem above by providing a similar example that does compile.  A more relevant sample that shows the same compiler error is here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ea3ca0a6591eabb1b74ae75f1317085e&version=stable

Comment: Highly likely to be a duplicate of [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423). You have a single struct containing both `Box<StreamingIterator>` and a `gzip::Decoder`. The iterator returns references to itself and you try to keep them in the decoder; thus trying to store a reference to itself inside of itself.

Comment: Well, possibly, but it's very unclear how.  
The intent is to borrow a reference from the Iterator, and store a decoder that uses that borrowed reference, allowing a reference to that decoder to be borrowed on.  The iterator returns references to a slice, which shouldn't, as I understand, it be tied to the iterator instance